# Solving $z^2(1-|z^2|)=-20$

Tags: complex-analysis

Writing in exponential form I get: $$|z^2|e^{2i\theta}-|z^4|e^{2i\theta}=20e^{i(0+2k\pi)}$$ $$e^{2i\theta}(|z^2|-|z^4|)=20e^{i(0+2k\pi)}$$ But then $|z^2|-|z^4|=20$ for no real number.How can |z| be found?

Comment: Real solution is $z=\pm\sqrt5$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $$z=x+iy$$ then we get
$$(x^2-y^2+2xyi)(1-\sqrt{(x^2-y^2)^2+4x^2y^2}=-20$$ Can you solve this equation?
We get the system
$$x^2-y^2-x^4+y^4+20=0$$
$$2xy-2xy(x^2+y^2)=0$$

Comment: Do you mean $2xy-2xy(x^2+y^2)$

Comment: It was a typo,sorry!

Comment: The first part is clear to me,but why would we get $1-x^2-y^2$ in the second parathesis letting $z=x+iy$?

Comment: Since $$z=x+yiy$$ we get $$z^2=x^2-y^2+2xyi$$ and $$|z^2|=\sqrt{(x^2-y^2)^2+4x^2y^2}$$ and this is $$\sqrt{x^4+y^4-2x^2y^2+4x^2y^2}$$ and this is $$x^2+y^2$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner But then, $2xy=2xy(x^2+y^2)$ and $x^2+y^2=1$ so if I replace $x^2=1-y^2$ into first equation ,everything cancels out leaving me with $20=0$

Comment: You can not cancle $$2xy$$ this can be also Zero!

Comment: True,but does the fact that when I cancel $2xy$ and replace the result in other equation having $0=20$ tells me $2xy=xy=0$ so at least one of $x,y$ has to be zero?Because if I take $y=0$ I have $x^4-x^2-20=0$ which gives me my result.

Comment: Yes, one of the $$x,y$$ has to be zero, since $$x^2+y^2=1$$ is not possible.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly,$z^2$ is real,

if $a=z^2,$ we have $$0=(|a|-1)a-20$$

Check if $a\ge0$ and when $a<0$

Comment: It is not at all clear that $z$ is real. Do you say that because the right side is real and the left side involves $z$? If $z$ is pure imaginary, the left side is also real. It may well be true, but you should provide more reasoning to reach this conclusion.

Comment: @MPW, Sorry it should be $z^2$

Comment: Okay, that *is* clear. Thanks for correcting. +1.